# Is there any site about culture worldwide?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question like:

> Do Asian cultures think feral dogs visiting their house is a good
>   event, but bad luck for feral cats? If so, what is the meaning and
>   reason behind it?

Even though it is about cats and dogs, it seems not to be well received in Pets, and I think it is more a question about culture. Is there any site where I can ask this type of question?

Comment: What about questions like is there an equivalent of Eurovision in Asia? Would a Euroasia vision be welcome why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is a bit broad given that there are many Asian cultures. Also, as you are asking about 'feral' animals - these are not pets at all.

Looking at the sites, I do not think that there is any site that is a specific culture-based Q & A site.

Answer (score 1):

My educated guess is that the question is on-topic on [Mythology SE](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/), where folklore is also on-topic (and they [consider changing their name to reflect this](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/308/873)). Compare, e.g., to [this question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/1687/873). I am however not very familiar with the scope of that site.